# Learning the 433Mhz signal of a remote car starter

Tags: gpio

I recently discovered that my remote car starter (Excalibur brand, with FCC ID L2M111) uses 433.92 Mhz RF to transmit the signal to start my car, so I thought I could learn the code and start my car using pilight-send like I've done with my 8 Etekcity outlets using the raw protocol, but I am not having much luck.  I keep trying to send the code, but the car doesn't seem to like it - no effect at all.

I know that the signal's strong enough to reach the detached garage where the car is.  I took one of my etekcity outlets out there and was able to control it from the pi in my living room just fine.

So... does anyone know what other variables might be used by the remote to send its signal, like sending different signals in a series (which I doubt) or sending them in pairs, or perhaps repeated with different timed gaps?

I know that the remote has 2 features, each controlled with the single button it has:

1. Hitting the button twice within 5 seconds of one another starts the car.
2. Holding the button for 3 seconds unlocks the car (specifically for cars which disable keyless entry while the car is running).

I feel pretty confident in my learned codes.  I took the mode of both the number of values seen in the debug output and the mode of each individual value across a couple hundred detected codes (of the same length) from the remote.  That strategy worked great for etekcity.  I even searched through the debug output for alternating codes and timings.  I can't seem to figure it out.

I have tried a number of patterns.  I've even gone so far as to replay all of the codes (whose length was seen more than once over the course of learning) detected by pilight-debug.

I also read in the manual that the device in the car has a feature to learn new codes from a replacement remote, but I'm not ready to start messing with that yet.

Comment: `learn` the codes several times and compare the results ... are all three versions the same?

Comment: What is your car model ?

Comment: Yeah, the first code I optimized was based on a couple hundred lines of the same length code and each value had been seen in its slot at least 10 times before I stopped learning. When the optimized code wasn't working, I started running my learning script in debug mode and I visually looked at stacks of dozens of codes. They appear consistent with the optimized code with a reasonable margin of error.

Comment: It's a Toyota RAV4, but the remote starter was added by the previous owner. It's Excalibur brand.

Comment: I can see [here](https://fccid.io/L2M111/User-Manual/User-Manual-1012456) `CODE JUMPING`

Comment: I've been looking at that same doc. What do you mean by "code jumping"?

Comment: Ah, I found it. It's literally in the doc.

Comment: Mean: `The RS-210-DP's Code Jumping renders such 'code grabbing' devices useless by randomly changing each signal that the transmitter sends`

Comment: Ah... I see. That makes sense. I knew there had to be some security trick. That's good I guess. Submit as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: No problem I create an anwer. Sorry for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see here [CODE JUMPING](https://fccid.io/L2M111/User-Manual/User-Manual-1012456)

> The RS-210-DP's Code Jumping renders such 'code grabbing' devices
>   useless by randomly changing each signal that the transmitter sends

Otherwise it would mean that anyone could play the code and so this create a big security problem.

Comment: It's not impossible, but it will take some effort to determine how the code sequence is generated. There are many algorithms for generating these code sequences, generically known as "Pseudo Random Number Generators". They are, by necessity, 'deterministic', and that generally means they can be "broken". They are not "secure" in the sense that good cryptography is; rather they depend on 'security through obscurity'. Lots of info on line - [here's one](https://jazzy.id.au/2010/09/20/cracking_random_number_generators_part_1.html)

Comment: Yes but it is not possible for lambda user, else put answer.

Comment: I wouldn't assume what is or is not possible for any user. I'm not answering because: a) off-topic, and b) I'm too lazy. I only piped in because you've implied it can't be done, and that's simply not correct.

Comment: `you've implied it can't be done` , until proof to the contrary yes.

Comment: If you're waiting on me for proof, please don't hold your breath :)

Comment: @Seamus, Sorry I do not understand the end of your sentence. I do not expect anything from you and I have not seen anything on this model in question even if I think so, you're right in the 'end'.

Comment: Sorry for the vernacular, but you can trust me on this one - it can be done.  :)